# clickable div is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want div2 to be clickable. However it is not working. What am I doing wrong here?

(Code has been updated after reading comments)
Note  : If I set div3 as clickable, it is working. changing back to div2 doesnt work. div1 also doesnt work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
    <title>Test Code</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

        .div1 {
            position: fixed; 
            width: 250px; 
            height: 80%; 
            border-style: solid; 
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .div2 {
            position: fixed; 
            width: 240px; 
            height: 50px; 
            border-style: solid; 
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .div3 {
            position: fixed; 
            width: 100%; 
            height: 80%; 
            border-style: solid;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div >
        <div >
            <div class="div1" >
                <div class="div2" id="item" >
                    This div should be clickable
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="div3">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".div2").click(function() {
                window.alert("sometext");
                $('.div3').html(function() {
                    var emph = '<em>' + $('p').length + ' paragraphs!</em>';
                    return '<p>All new content for ' + emph + '</p>';
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry, but why are you using `.div1.div2`? If you just want to make `.div2` clickable, you can simply use `.div2`. Also: Could you update the code above to reflect the changes you made?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Put a space in your selector (`.div1 .div2`). Currently you're selecting for an element that has *both* `div1` and `div2` classes.
2. Wrap your code in `$(function() { ... });` to fire it when the DOM is ready.
3. `div3` is styled to cover both `div1` and `div2`. Give `div1` `z-index: 1` to make it sit above `div3`.

[Here's a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/f8hFK/)

Comment: The code still won't work since it's running before the elements it refers to exist in the page.

Answer (score 3):

By placing your jQuery code before the actual element, the jQuery code does not yet know that `.div2` is in the DOM.

Try either wrapping your jQuery code in `$(document).ready()` or moving it below those elements. And also, put a comma to separate your elements in your click function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".div1, .div2").click(function() {
            window.alert("sometext");
            $('.div3').html(function() {
                var emph = '<em>' + $('p').length + ' paragraphs!</em>';
                return '<p>All new content for ' + emph + '</p>';
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: A comma in the selector is going to apply the click handler to both div1 and div2. I believe it should be ".div1 .div2" instead.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to wrap your code in

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".div1 .div2").on('click', function() {
        $('.div3').html('<p>All new content for <em>' + $('p').length + ' paragraphs!</em></p>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM is not finished loading when your script is excecuted. This means that the div with class 'div2' does not exist when you asign a click event handler to it. Wrap your code in `$(document).ready( );`

Comment: done all the mentioned changes. still its not working. I want to click on div2 and change contents of div3. Want to do it using jquery only.